# Arduino - My problem is when the condition is greater than 900.00 it will continue the loop and do the code below once

Tags: arduino-uno

I want is to stop the loop and when it read  Greater than 900.00 again it will do task again.

I need condition. When it back to greater than 900.00 the code below will do task and then it will stop. And when it will reach the condition again it will do the code again and it will stop .. Please help me

```
void loop(){
  float reading = analogRead(LIGHTSENSORPIN); //Read light level
  float square_ratio = reading / 1023.0;      //Get percent of maximum value (1023)
  square_ratio = pow(square_ratio, 2.0);      //Square to make response more obvious

  analogWrite(LEDPIN, 255.0 * square_ratio);  //Adjust LED brightness relatively
  analogWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 255.0 * square_ratio);  //Adjust LED brightness relatively
  Serial.println(reading);                    //Display reading in serial monitor



if(reading >= 900.00){

  digitalWrite(smDirectionPin, LOW); //Writes the direction to the EasyDriver DIR pin. (LOW is counter clockwise).
    /*Turns the motor fast 1600 steps*/ 
      for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
    digitalWrite(smStepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(700);
    digitalWrite(smStepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(700);
}
}

  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: You need to also store the old reading. Then change the `if` to `if(oldReading<900.00 and reading>=900.00)`

Comment: how can i store the old reading??

Comment: Please post your code, instead of an image.

Comment: Sir can u please modify my code to do that?

Comment: anybody can help?? please..

Comment: `how can i store the old reading??`  the first line in `loop()` stores  a reading .... the second line did something with that reading and stored the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setup(){ ....
......
}
float old_reading=0;
loop() {
float reading = analogRead(LIGHTSENSORPIN); //Read light level
// ... do this always (maybe empty) 
// in your code it is LED shining and printing
if ((old_reading<=900) && (reading>900)) {
   // ... do this just just once when reading goes over 900 up
   // in your code it is manipulating motor
   }
old_reading=reading;
// ... do this always , but after special part (maybe empty)
// in your code it is just delay
}
```

- So on begining `old_reading` is just zero, but being declared outside `loop`, it keeps its value between different runs of `loop`.
- the `if (condition)` does not hit, as `reading` is less than 900 (if it starts with more then 900, see next part)
- the end with `old_reading=reading;` makes `old_reading` to be the last known value of `reading`
- when `reading` goes Greater than 900 for first time, the `old_reading` is Less or Equal 900 (as it was the last value of `reading` before it crossed 900 up.
- - so the `if (condiotion)` is true and you start moving motor
- - then (on the end) you set `old_reading=reading;` and `old_reading` is also larger then 900
- - while `reading` stays over 900 in next loops, the `old_reading` does so, and therefore the `if (condition)` does not hit - `(old_reading<=900)` is not true
- - when `reading` falls down 900 or lower, the `if(condition)` also does not hit, but after that the `old_reading=reading;` makes `old_reading` less or equal 900
- and so we are at the start again, skipping the part after `if(condition)` until `reading` gets Greater than 900 (then we run motor, set `old_reading` to something greater than 900 and we already was here and know, how it works :)

Comment: Thank you sir gilhad... i appreciate your time and effort doing this.. keep helping others

Comment: :) This is just basic programming (not even about Arduino) - you really should read more articles/books about programming and read examples and shorter programs and try to understand it by yourself - it will give much more understanding. I suggest to read arduino.cc and/or other sites about arduino and about programming for beginers. Really pays off in long term :)